# why Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'shortcutShortLabel' in package 'android' when creating shourtcut in Android7?

Tags: android

When I create a shortcut refer to the developer.android.com,
the code I wrote is below

```
<shortcuts xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<shortcut
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/share"
    android:shortcutId="search"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/recommend_us"
    android:shortcutLongLabel="@string/recommend_to_friend"
    android:shortcutDisabledMessage="@string/bind_unbound">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetPackage="com.example.myapplication"
        android:targetClass="com.yidian.news.ui.search.SearchChannelActivity" />
</shortcut>
<!-- Specify more shortcuts here. -->
```

A simple one. But when I build the project, here comes out error message says

Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'shortcutId' in package 'android'

Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'shortcutShortLabel' in package 'android'

Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'shortcutLongLabel' in package 'android'
Error:(2) No resource identifier found for attribute 'shortcutDisabledMessage' in package 'android'

why is that

have upgrade all Android SDK & tools

Comment: post your build.gradle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortcuts require Android 7.1 . ie, API level 25